# Adding RAM is being converted to swap

Tags: ram, swap, syslinux

I am not completely sure if in the right website (though I think I am). 
Anyway, my problem is I wanted to increse the available RAM in my machine from 8 to 16GB. I got another memory (exact same one as currently installed) and added to the socket.

When I power up my linux, it is displaying still only 8GB of RAM and now a 8GB of swap and I have no idea why? Is this normal? Can I free the swap to actually be RAM? Reason for this is because my IDE and searches consume a lot so it is just a matter of time until it reaches to 8GB and start wanting to write to the disk.

Sorry if it is a pretty obvious solution, I just have no idea! All I have managed to discover in regards to this was for problems that swap was part of the disk (from my understanding) which is not exactely what I am going through

Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Comment: Does BIOS/UEFI settings report your installed 16 GB RAM?  If not, the new RAM module isn't recognized -- either not fully seated, or not supported by the MB.

Comment: @ZeissIkon good shout! Let me quickly check :)

Comment: You can also check the output of `sudo dmidecode -t memory` for more information about the installed and recognized RAM modules

Comment: Nice one! Thank you guys for helping through this! I managed to confirm both on bios and CMD the upgrade ^^ The slot offers a lot of resistance in comparison with the ones I used previously so made me think it was actually well placed. A very tiny click at the end proved me wrong. Anyway now is working and I am embarrassed! Live and learn eh? :') Once again, thank you! :3 More than happy to consider correct answer @ZeissIkon, if you want to provide one

Comment: Now in the form of an answer, incorporating the command from @ByteCommander.  Hardware questions are off topic here, but for this it's hard to be certain its hardware until it's fixed -- and it might be helpful to others over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symptoms you describe sound very much as if the new memory you installed isn't being recognized.

As a hardware question, this is slightly off topic here, but you don't know it's a hardware question when you start.  If BIOS/UEFI settings doesn't recognize the RAM, or (without restarting) it doesn't show with `sudo dmidecode -t memory` (thanks, @ByteCommander), it may mean the new module didn't seat as it should.

Running through the installation process again (watch for a never-used memory slot being stiffer than one that's had a module in it for a while) is likely to fix you up.